# ¿como desde un template borrar ekementos ?tanto del arreglo como de la vuista del usuario

Tags: javascript

tengo este template el cual intento mediantee l boton eliminar un elemento tanto del arreglo como de la vsia del ussuario, pero ni siquiera llega al metodo

```
<template id="templateRowCarrito">
     <tr class="ItemCarrito" id="C_${id}">
     <td>${id}</td>

      <td>
      <span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">0</span>
      <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      </td>
     </tr>
     
    </template>

const arreglo=[]

const Clickbuttondelete = document.querySelectorAll('.delete')


console.log(Clickbuttondelete)
```

acá recorro e botón

```
Clickbuttondelete.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
})
```

aqui trato de hacer el intento de eliminar, pero no se elimina ni del arreglo ni de la vsita del que ocupa el pc(digitador)

```
function removeItem(e){
  console.log('llega')
 
  const buttonDelete = e.target
  
  const title = document.querySelector('.id').textContent;
  for(let i=0; i<arreglo.length ; i++){

    if(arreglo[i].id.trim() === title){
      arreglo.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }

  const alert = document.querySelector('#second-tab >#form2>.alert')
  

  setTimeout( function(){
    alert.classList.add('remove')
  }, 2000)
    alert.classList.remove('remove')

  tr.remove()

  
  
}
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, Js no es lo mio, pero creo que el problema puede estar en que seleccionas el elemento por clase, lo que te trae un array de elementos, tal vez si usas una "ID", se solucione.